# How to prove some statistical model to be dominated?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, modeling, model

I have a model following the PDF $$f_\theta(x) = \theta^2 x \exp(-\theta x)\delta_{[0, +\infty)}(x)$$ where $\theta > 0$ is the parameter and $\delta_\mathcal{S}$ denotes the indicator function of the set $\mathcal{S}$.

I am ask to prove that this model is **regular**, for which I have to prove that it is **dominated**. How should I do that?

Below is the definition of "dominated" that I found the the book *Theory of Point Estimation* by E.L. Lehmann and George Casella:

> Statistical problems are concerned not with single probability
>   distributions but with families of such distributions $$\mathcal{P} = \{P_\theta, \theta\in\Omega\}$$ defined over a common measurable space
>   $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{A})$. When all the distributions of
>   $\mathcal{P}$ are absolutely continuous with respect to a common
>   measure $\mu$, as will usually be the case, the family $\mathcal{P}$
>   is said to be dominated (by $\mu$).
>
> Most of the examples with which we shall deal belong to one or the
>   other of the following two cases.
>
> (i) The discrete case. Here, $\mathcal{X}$ is a countable set,
>   $\mathcal{A}$ is the class of subsets of $\mathcal{X}$, and the
>   distributions of $\mathcal{P}$ are dominated by counting measure.
>
> (ii) The absolutely continuous case. Here, $\mathcal{X}$ is a Borel
>   subset of a Euclidean space, $\mathcal{A}$ is the class of Borel
>   subsets of $\mathcal{X}$, and the distributions of $\mathcal{P}$ are
>   dominated by Lebesgue measure over $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{A})$.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: can you define what "regular" and "dominated" mean?

Comment: @Chaconne I have updated with a definition of "dominated". Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the update. So the definition discusses measures but you've already got a density which mean that, by definition, each of your $f_\theta$ is equal to $\frac{\text d P_\theta}{\text d\mu_\theta}$ for some $\mu_\theta$. This means for each $P_\theta$ you have a dominating measure so you then need to show that all these $\mu_\theta$ are in fact the same measure $\mu$, and that measure dominates $\{P_\theta\}$. Do you know what the $\mu_\theta$ are?

Comment: @Chaconne No all I'm given is the above PDF :( Another definition of "dominated": https://www2.cirano.qc.ca/~dufourj/Web_Site/ResE/Dufour_1998_C_AdvEtx_StatisticalModels.ps I guess they are equivalent.

Comment: The quotation demonstrates that "dominated by Lebesgue measure" and "absolutely continuous" are synonymous.